# How to Authenticate User without Password

Tags: jhipster

i am working on jhipster.jhipster authentication is working fine for me with UserName and Password.but i want to authenticate user only using userName not with combination of username and password please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Authentication only with username is no real authentication unless the username is private. Are you asking about automatic authentication with user ssl keys?

Comment: Yes my userName is not private but i have integrate Facebook login when user login from fb so not need to authenticate here with password here in case these email need to authenticate with username only.

Comment: Either your user is already authenticated (via Faceook OAuth) or not

Comment: Yes authenticated  via Facebook Oauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read in your comments you are using the Facebook login, JHipster uses Spring Security which support OpenID authentication, you should have a look at it. I have a similar application which uses it (it's Spring XML configuration, not JavaConfig, but it should be very close to JHipster as I coded both projects):

[applicationContext-security.xml](https://github.com/ippontech/tatami/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml)

Comment: Thanks for reply ...you mean we have to use openid-login process for authenticate the user